# Standard Button that points to visualforce page but not visible in communities

Tags: visualforce, community

As i say in the title, i have a standard button ("New") which points to a visualforce page, but this button is not visible in the communities. Why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Comment: Check if you have a different layout for the community, if yes check if the button is added there. Check if the community user profile has access to the visualforce page and apex class.

Comment: i have only one layout regarding the object i want to include in the community. I am also admin in the system so i have access to both vf and apex class.

Comment: Have you assigned permission in the community user profile to the Visualforce page?